# Build a collection of object using EF, C#, linq (Dictionary<string,List<string,string>>)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, wcf, linq-to-objects

I originally (mistakenly) posted this on the codereview site.

I'm building a WCF service to retrieve a list of "AttributeName,AttributeGroup,AttributeValue"

For example,

```
AttributeName      AttributeGroup           AttributeValue
Document Type      Information Systems      User Guide
Document Type      Information Systems      Installation Instructions
Document Type      Information Systems      Policy
Document Type      Finance                  Financial Statements
Application        null                     ECM
Application        null                     HR
Application        null                     eData
Interest           Survey               1 - Sign Me Up
Interest           Survey               2 - Very Interested
Interest           Survey               3 - Would Try
Interest           Survey               4 - Would Watch
Interest           Survey               5 - Not at all
```

So far, so good. I want the WCF service to return a strongly-typed object:

```
[DataContract]
public class Categories
{
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string, Category> CategoryList { get; set; }

    public Categories ()
    {
        CategoryList = new Dictionary<string, Category>();
    }
}

public class Category
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public CategoryLookupValues LookupValues {get;set;}


    public Category(string categoryName,CategoryLookupValues values)
    {
        CategoryName = categoryName;
        LookupValues = values;

    }


}
public class CategoryLookupValues
{

    [DataMember]
    public string AttributeName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string,string> AttributeValues { get; set; }

    public CategoryLookupValues(string attributeName,ILookup<string,string> values)
    {
        AttributeName = attributeName;
        AttributeValues = AttributeValues;
    }

}
```

(don't nitpick just yet at my contract, still just trying to figure out how to populate the objects)  :)

I'm using EF to get data from the database and I'm trying to use linq to populate the objects... I've gone through a few iterations and just can't put my finger on it.

By the way the CategoryName attribute is passed in as a parameter and is not part of the results.

I was messing around with the following:

```
var lookup = (
from attributeGroup in model.ECMGeneralLookups 
from attributeValue in model.ECMGeneralLookups 
where attributeGroup.AttributeName.Equals("DocType")
select new{attributeGroup,attributeValue}
).ToLookup(x=>x.attributeValue,x=>x.attributeGroup);
```

(ECMGeneralLookups) is the table with the three columns at the start of the post.

Comment: I pasted the structure of the table (AttributeName,AttributeGroup,AttributeValue)
I also pasted the object structure I'm trying to convert my db results to
(Categories, Category,CategoryLookupValues)

I believe what I need is Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,List<string>>>

AttributeName<AttributeGroup<AttributeValues>>

Answer (score 0):

hard to tell what your database table is.. but it looks like you want something like.. 
var lookup= model.ECMGeneralLookups.Where(x=>x.AttributeName=="DocType").Select(x=>new{x.attributeGroup, x.attributeValue}).FirstOrDefault();

(or you can replace select with ToLookup)

Comment: Looking at ToLookup()... Looks like it would would great but would need help with that one as well.

I was able to successfully retrieve the data ToLookup() but I'm trying to draw the parallel with my business objects and how I can populate those to return them through the WCF service.